# MongoDB: Sort of a map-reduce, but not quite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

I've got a node/mongo web application. In the mongo database, I have a (very large -- in the millions) collection of documents called "stories". Each story has a few basic properties ("title", "author", "text", etc). I'm experimenting with a few machine learning algorithms that attempt to classify the text into different "moods".

Each of the different classifier algorithms has a record in the "algorithms" collection, which consists of a name and a "score", which represents how successfully the algorithm is performing.

I store all the classification results in a collection called "detectedMoods"; each record holds the storyID, algorithmID, and a list of detected moods.

Here's where we finally get to my question:

I want to keep a list of detected moods for each story IN the story document, where the list in the story document is the one generated by the Algorithm that currently has the highest "score". There's no guarantee that every algorithm will have been run on every story, and it's always possible to either add a new Algorithm with a higher score, or for the scores to change... though that will NOT happen very often (maybe once every couple of days). So it needs to work something like this:

For each Story, among the Algorithms where we have a detectedMoods record for this Story's storyID, find the one with the highest Score, and then store that algorithm's detected moods list in the "detectedMoods" property of the Story along with the algorithmID of the Algorithm that was used.

It feels like some variation of Map-Reduce makes sense here, but I can't figure how how to quite fit it into that model... Any thoughts? Do I need to do some scripting, or is this doable within a single Mongo command?

== Update, per request ==

Commenter requested example documents, so here goes.

**Stories** collection:

```
{
    "_id":"s01",
    "Title":"Misery",
    "Author":"Stephen King",
    "Text":"......",
}
{
    "_id":"s02",
    "Title":"Catch-22",
    "Author":"Joseph Heller",
    "Text":"......",
}
```

**Algorithms** collection:

```
{
    "_id":"c01",
    "Name":"algorithm A",
    "Score":104
}
{
    "_id":"c02",
    "Name":"algorithm B",
    "Score":22
}
```

**DetectedMoods** collection:

```
{
    "_id":"fh3fha",
    "algorithmID":"c01",
    "storyID":"s01",
    "moods":["desperate","afraid","bitter"]
}
{
    "_id":"m12y49",
    "algorithmID":"c02",
    "storyID":"s01",
    "moods":["bored","unhappy"]
}
{
    "_id":"fj37ah",
    "algorithmID":"c02",
    "storyID":"s02",
    "moods":["confused"]
}
```

**Stories** collection updates from pseudo-map-reduce:

```
{
    <...Misery...>
    "moods":["desperate","afraid","bitter"],
    "algorithm":"c01"
}
{
    <...Catch-22...>
    "moods":["confused"],
    "algorithm":"c02"
}
```

So, both algorithms (c01 and c02) were used to process "Misery", and as c01 has a better Score than c02, its results are the ones that get stored in the Story document for that story, along with a property that shows c01 was the source of those moods. However, "Catch-22" was processed only with c02, so it's the best option we have for that story, and thus its list of moods for that story is the one that gets stored in the Story document.

Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Unfortunately way too-broad and not really answerable without an example case of what you want to achieve. Needs documents and not words. Sounds like a "weighted sort", but of course the method depends on specific data and details.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Updated to include documents; hopefully this clarifies things. Thanks!

Comment: It clarifies that you are looking for a "JOIN". Seems to be commonplace that people misread that `mapReduce` is a way of performing a "JOIN", and it basically is not. Modern MongoDB releases include [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which can do "join like" operations, if of course you have MongoDB 3.2.x or greater. But otherwise you are basically running multiple queries to retrieve the "related" items.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I don't really see how you'd accomplish this with a Join... it would at least require a subquery I'd think, since we only want the results from the highest-ranked Algorithm that was run on each story. Map-reduce seems like a closer analog; a common use would be, say, to store the number of Employees in a Department document by counting up the Employee records with that DepartmentID. In this case, it's more akin to storing the highest-paid employee per department in the Department record, i.e. a MAX operation instead of a COUNT... no?

Comment: Well if you have `$lookup` it's quite easy. You fetch the matching algorithms and then `$sort` the results by score and just keep the largest one. Same applies to multiple queries. So those are your only options. `mapReduce` is not suited to that type of "joining". And what you are asking does in fact require a "join" or "lookup" of the related data in other collections.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I see what you mean re "join" at least in the broader sense. I have $lookup in my dev environment, will have to make sure it's available in all of the places I'm going to be deploying. Thanks.